# Draw a line in Processing that keeps turning right and changes color

Tags: python, processing

So basically what I'm trying to do is recreate Posavec's [Sentence Drawings](http://www.notcot.com/images/2008/04/Sentence-Drawings-Poster.jpg) in Processing. The idea is that a long line represents a whole book: the line's color is determined by the theme of a sentence in the book, its length is determined by the number of words in that sentence, and the line turns right every time a new sentence is started. 
To do this I am using Processing in Python mode. My idea is to turn every sentence into a list consisting of 2 items: first; a number corresponding to a color, and second; the number of words in that sentence. All these small lists can then be compiled into a list of lists looking something like this:

```
Sentences = [[2,9],[4,5],[3,3],[8,15],[1,8],[5,7],[9,25],[0,12],[7,6],[6,14]]
```

The idea, then, in Processing, is to use this list of lists to draw the line.
I was thinking something along the following:

```
For item in Sentences:
    if item[0] is 0:
        stroke(R,G,B)
    elif item[0] is 1:
        stroke(R,G,B)
    etc. for all color options
```

This is just for the color of the line, but I can't even get this part to work. I'll have to add more code that tells Processing to draw a line as long as item[ 1 ] (or Sentences[ item ][ 1 ]), and turns right for every new item in Sentences (i.e. for every new sentence). I have no idea where to start here, though. This seems quite tricky to me seeing as the line() function in Processing requires 2 sets of x and y coordinates. I thought it might be better to draw the lines using vectors but have no idea how these works yet.

I'm quite new to all this, so don't have much of an idea of how either processing or python works (just the basics). Maybe I'm not approaching this right, could anyone help out?

Comment: So you want a tutorial on about a dozen basic topics while simultaneously hoping someone will write all the code for you?

Comment: Or a push in the right direction

Comment: seems like everything you're doing is already in the right direction except posting this off topic question. If you Google for tutorials on the missing pieces, you'll be able to figure this out pretty quickly. SO is not the right place for this sort of question though

Comment: Alright, good to know. Thanks anyway!

Comment: One concrete piece of advice I have for you though is not to have that giant set of `if` `elif` for the color selection. If you can't figure out a very simple function for mapping number to rgb, at least use a dictionary to store the mapping.

Comment: Also `for` is lowercase in Python and variables should have lowercase names by convention.

Comment: The best advice we can give you is to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and then take those pieces on one at a time. Create a simple example program that does just one small part of the whole. If you get stuck, you can post a [mcve] along with a more specific question. Good luck.